# Bundle file location in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-optimization

Where are the generated bundle files placed?

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryall")
   .IncludeDirectory("~/scripts/", "*.js", true)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are no files, [bundles are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928336/asp-net-bundling-caching-where-and-how-long) [stored in-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17663030/can-you-pre-cache-asp-net-bundles).

Can you please explain why you expect the bundles to be files? :-)

Comment: Thanks; I'm marking your response as the answer because of the supporting links

Comment: Thanks. If you can explain your original problem (why you need access to the file), you can start a new question with it if you want, perhaps there's another solution to it. :-)

Answer (score 6):

They are bundled up dynamically (in Memory I assume) and served to the client being sent down to the client as a single item (you should the single JS file see it if you use fiddler of F12 => Network).

Comment: Thanks. I would mark your answer as correct as well but I can only  check one and your's seemed to lack certainty. I did use the Developer Tools Network and Scripts tab and I did see the url to the script but I was wondering if there was a physical file used on the server to generate the response.